# Date function runs twice in vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, google-chrome, frontend, laravel-blade

I have written a `Showdate` function for my HTML blade , but last time working with it I faced with a weird situation where the code runs twice and outputs the data 2 times.
The function worked without any problem before.The below code is inside blade:

```
<div v-for="day in Days">
                <p >@{{ShowDate(day.Date)}}</p>
</div>
```

Whenever I run the above code with `Days:[{Date:"2021-03-06"},{Date:"2021-03-07"},{Date:"2021-03-08"}]` console logs the below results:

```
        2021-03-07
        2021-03-08
        2021-03-06
        2021-03-07
        2021-03-08
        2021-03-06
```

and this is my function:

```
ShowDate: function(date) {
            return date
          },
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need this function. You can acces the day's Date property directly like:

```
<p>@{{day.Date}}</p>
```

Comment: thanks for your comment , but I need to process some data there and the above function in just for test

Comment: I tried this code and it executed exactly 3 times, not 6. Can you maybe provide more of your code?